When I try to install Pillow, I encounter this error
(env) PS D:\programing\source\Backend\Django> python -m pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached pillow-10.3.0.tar.gz (46.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Building wheel for Pillow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for Pillow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [216 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_deprecate.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_typing.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src\pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no files found matching '.flake8'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'renovate.json'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'wheels'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\PIL\_imaging.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_imagingcms.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_imagingft.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_imagingmath.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_imagingmorph.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_webp.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      copying src\PIL\py.typed -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-311\PIL
      running build_ext
     
     
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
     
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1009, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 104, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 967, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\normal\lib\python3.11\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 967, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 967, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 91, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 359, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "<string>", line 826, in build_extensions
      RequiredDependencyException: zlib
     
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\programing\source\Backend\Django\env\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\programing\source\Backend\Django\env\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\programing\source\Backend\Django\env\lib\python3.11\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0o1gts_1\pillow_63b6db6c73014bb0b5889af20ec1aade\_custom_build\backend.py", line 26, in build_wheel
          return super().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings, metadata_directory)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0o1gts_1\pillow_63b6db6c73014bb0b5889af20ec1aade\_custom_build\backend.py", line 20, in run_setup
          return super().run_setup(setup_script)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\mahdimoradiz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vhix2unp\overlay\lib\python3.11\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 1025, in <module>
      RequiredDependencyException:
     
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
     
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
     
     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I uninstalled and installed Python, I also uninstalled and installed the virtual environment, but I don't know where the problem is

I read it for you and extracted the important part: "The headers or library files could not be found for zlib".

Correct way py -m pip install pillow Not capital P Released: Apr 1, 2024

@KlausD. Why wouldn't pip automatically locate and install zlib?  If you know, it would make a good answer.

@toyotaSupra PyPI and similar indices don't distinguish upper/lower cases. pip install Pillow works. The OP has a different problem.

Your error message says:

The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

A similar issue was raised and one of the suggestions is to install zlib which is what your error message says.
Another user said setting this env variables worked:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig" 
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"                
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"


Please note the OP uses Msys/Mingw so the issue should be one of those: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues?q=is%3Aissue+mingw+zlib
